# yeoman angular generator generated app throws angular undefined error

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I made sure the angular js files is loaded before the other scripts and still i get the undefined error

screenshots:
[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of here is that the virtual directory to the bower_components folder (one level up from the app folder) is not there or not working.

Check the Net tab in firebug and makes sure angular.js is not 404-ing.  My guess is that it is.

You'll need to make sure that whatever server you are running has the bower_components folder referenced virtually.  For default Yeoman angular projects using Grunt, it looks something like this:

```
...
connect().use(
    '/bower_components',
     connect.static('./bower_components')
 )
...
```